# How to show or hide element based on 5 boolean values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, boolean-logic

I have a page that has "items" on it that you can drag around. There are filters that the user can apply to only show an item based on a certain criteria.

There are also folders that the user can see on the same page where various items are stored. The user can click on a folder to view its items.

I am having trouble with the logic for showing or hiding items based on the filters. (Also, I am using AngularJS's `ng-class` directive to apply an "item-showing" CSS class).

For example, I want to:

> Always hide the item if the item is in a different folder than the
>   currently viewed folder.
>
> Otherwise: If the "must be starred" filter is applied, and the item is
>   starred, show it.
>   **OR**
>   If the "must be complete" filter is applied, and
>   the item is marked as complete, show it.
>
> If the "must be starred" and "must be complete" filters are applied,
>   and the item is neither starred nor complete, hide it.

I've tried several different ways of doing this, such as:

```
class="item" ng-class="{'item-showing': item.isInCurrentFolder && ((item.mustBe.starred && item.starred) || (item.mustBe.complete && item.complete))}"
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    /* various styles */
    display: none;
}

.item-showing {
    display: block;
}
```

Each item's JavaScript properties look similar to this:

```
{
    // various properties, and then...

    isInCurrentFolder: true,
    starred: true,
    complete: true,
    mustBe: {
        starred: false,
        complete: false
    }
}
```

I have a service that will change `mustBe.starred` and `mustBe.complete` to `true` or `false`, depending on whether the user clicks a checkbox to apply the "must be starred" or "must be complete" filters.

Long story short, the logic is flawed, and/or the architecture for each item model is flawed. Clicking the checkboxes to apply the filters might hide an item, when it should show it, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: The ng-class directive should probably have object inside. Is this a typo?

Comment: @Frizi, yeah sorry, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: might be easier to use a directive and put the condition logic in directive where you can test it easier

Comment: @charlieftl, good point, might do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down your logic.

- Always hide the item if the item is in a different folder than the currently viewed folder

  ```
  item.isInCurrentFolder
  ```

  If the condition is not met, we won't be even testing any further.
- If the "must be starred" filter is applied, and the item is starred, show it.

  Rephrased: **If we don't care about starring, or if we care and it is starred**

  ```
  !item.mustBe.starred || item.starred
  ```
- If the "must be complete" filter is applied, and the item is marked as complete, show it.

  Apply the same reasoning

  ```
  !item.mustBe.complete || item.complete
  ```
- Combine logic

  **and** them, as each individual condition must be met

  ```
  item.isInCurrentFolder &&
  (!item.mustBe.starred || item.starred) &&
  (!item.mustBe.complete || item.complete)
  ```

Little demo in action: http://jsfiddle.net/vkQtp/

Comment: This is great, thanks for the answer. However, if I click both "must be starred" and "must be complete" filters at the same time, it does not show the item if it is not both starred **and** complete. However, if it is starred **or** complete, I would still like to show it, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Josh It should. true && (!true || true) && (!true || true) yields true. You may have an error on another level.

Comment: This is the problem I'm looking at now: an item that must be starred, and isn't starred, and must be complete, and is complete.  The logic looks like this: true && (!true || false) && (!true || true). This yields false; therefore, the item will not show, **even though it IS complete, but simply not starred**, if that makes sense. However, I **do** want to show this particular item.

Comment: @Josh what is your logic behind setting these values? Isn't it simply ng-model on the checkboxes?

Comment: @josh i made a little demo to show the logic and one of many possible ways to create such list.